# Where am I going wrong with this calculation of $\pi_1(T^2/ {\sim})$ where $\sim$ identifies two points on the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

So, I start off with this model:
[image]

It's clear to see that $U \cong S^1 \vee S^1$ and $U\cap V \cong S^1$. For $V$:
[image]

so $V\cong S^1$ also. So
$$
\pi_1(T^2\setminus {\sim}) = \frac{\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)*\pi_1(S^1)}{N} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}}{N}
$$
now we need to deal with the inclusions to get $N$. For ${f : \pi_1(U\cap V) \to \pi_1(U)}$, it's we have $f(1) = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ ($1$ is the generating loop in $U\cap V$). So basically ${\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}}$ get's abelianized to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. But for $g : \pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(V)$, $g(1) = 1$, so one of the copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ cancels so we get
$$
\pi_1(T^2\setminus {\sim}) = \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}
$$
However, the answer should be ${(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})*\mathbb{Z}}$ I think. What's wrong with my reasoning? I thought maybe $g(1)=1$ could be wrong, but I don't see how. A loop that goes around once in $U\cap V$ should be homotopy equivalent to the loop that goes around once in $V$?

Comment: "$1$ is the identity loop in $U \cap V$"...  $U \cap V$ contains one loop generating $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ and it is not the identity (in $U \cap V$ or $U$).  You might benefit from assigning that loop in $U \cap V$ a name and seeing how it pushes into $U$ and $V$.  Can the generating loop in $V$ be pushed into $U \cap V$?

Comment: @EricTowers sorry, yes, I didn't mean identity, I meant generating loop, I'll edit it now. But yes, if you let ${c}$ be the generating loop for example of ${\pi_1(U\cap V)}$ and ${d}$ be the generating loop of ${\pi_1(V)}$, wouldn't ${g(c) = d}$?

Comment: Re: $g(c) = d$.  Nope.  There's no way to thread one arc of that loop through the identified point.  (You can, of course, push it through as a hairpin, but that isn't going to take the one loop to the other.)  It could help to sketch a couple of steps in the deformation retract of $V$ to see that $c$ covers $d$ twice -- once one way and once the other.

Comment: @EricTowers ahhhh, I think I understand, I have attached a picture, is this the right idea to show ${g(c) = 0}$?

Comment: No.  If you attempt to shrink that loop onto the identified point, the closest you can get is a "figure 8".  Notice that $V$ is a once-punctured horn torus.  $c$ is a loop around the puncture.  As you deformation retract, $c$ is taken to the non-self-crossing path shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Standard_torus-horn.png), and as the boundary continues retracting onto the loop of $V$, $c$ covers it twice in opposite directions.

Comment: Are you under an impression that {curly braces} are needed in all MathJax expressions, as in `${x=y}$`, which is then rendered as $x=y\text{?}$ That's how you wrote this, but then you wrote `T^2/\sim` where {curly braces}, as in `T^2/{\sim}` would have resulted in proper horizontal spacing, thus $T^2/\sim$ versus $T^2/{\sim}.$ The former happens because the horizontal spacing is what is appropriate for a binary relation symbol. The latter is appropriate in this context because this time it is not being used as a binary relation symbol.